# Domed False bottom liquid during mash

Tags: wort

I have a 20 gallon space beneath my false bottom. Is it better to include this as mash water during the infusion or    not? If not, my grain\liquid ratio will be lower and therefore more watery pre-sparge

Comment: 20 gallons? Is this a 5 barrel system?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it would be a matter of how that volume relates to the overall volume of your mash.  Presumably your strike water and sparge water volumes are much larger than 20 gallons, potentially making it negligible (or at least within a reasonable amount of error/variance).  If your water additions are smaller and that 20 gallons is a large percentage of your mash/sparge volume, you will certainly need to take it into account, though I think mostly in terms of how much wort you collect.

Another option for addressing this (though for a system as large as I'm thinking your is it may be costly) may be fly/continuous sparging.  That way you're maintaining the volume required to cover the grains and are rinsing the converted sugars out efficiently.

That said, more details on your circumstance would be helpful to get a better idea of what your constraints are.

Answer (score 0):

I would include it, as it is water that you grains do not have "direct access" to.

As @thesquaregroot commented, you need enough water to cover your grains. Maybe do a test, add the water - 20 gallons to the mashtun, add the grains and see if the grains are covered and the liquid/grain ratio is to your preference. If not, add the extra 20 gallons of water.